# Can I use OR statements in Java switches?

Tags: java

I'm wondering if I can use `or` in `switch-case` in Java?

Example

```
switch (value)
{
   case 0:
      do();
      break;

   case 2 OR 3 
      do2();
      break;
}
```

Comment: Search for fall-through, that will get you there ;)

Comment: removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time :)

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time

Comment: aioobe answer is the correct one. But if you ever need to use the OR operator in another context it is '||'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no "or" operator in the case expressions in the Java language. You can however let one case "fall through" to another by omitting the `break` statement:

```
switch (value)
{
   case 0:
      do();
      break;

   case 2:  // fall through
   case 3:
      do2();
      break;
}
```