# Java Switch and Or statement

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use OR statements in Java switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566263/can-i-use-or-statements-in-java-switches)

I have a switch statement. Is there a way to do an or statement within the switch. Ie

```
switch(val){

case 1
//Do Stuff
break;

case 2
//Do Stuff
break;

case 3
//Do Stuff
break
}
```

Instead do something like

```
switch(val){

case 1 or 3
//Do Stuff
break;

case 2
//Do Stuff
break;

}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, try this:

```
switch(val){

    case 1: case 3:
        //Do Stuff
        break;

    case 2:
        //Do Stuff
        break;

    default:
        //Do Stuff
        break;

}
```

Always remember to include the default case too.

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(val) {

case 1:
case 3:
  //Do Stuff
  break;

case 2
  //Do Stuff
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
switch(val){
    case 1:
    case 2:
       //Do Stuff
       break;
    case 3:
       //Do Stuff
       break;
    default:
       break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(val) {

case 1:    
case 2:
   //Do Stuff
   break;       
case 3:
   //Do Stuff
   break;
}
```