# Code performed in every case of a switch case solution

Tags: java, switch-statement

Suppose i have a piece of code that should be performed in each of the cases of a switch case construct:

```
switch(myEnum){
  case A:
    System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
    break;
  case B:
    System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
    break;
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to avoid writing the line

```
System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
```

in each of the cases and defining a method called by each of the cases?

Comment: Why not just write that line above the switch statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 
System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
to execute in any case, you don't need to put it in switch case.
Also, if you place the statement in case B, and you don't put break statement in case A, then you will execute in both case A and case B

Answer (score 3):

If you have two cases which result int he same action, you could do something like so:

```
switch(myEnum){
  case A:    
  case B:
    System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
    break;
  ...
}
```

The test action for the test case `A` should trickle down to be handled by `B`.

Comment: doubt this is a good solution. Chances are, there are instructions that have to run in case A, but not case B (and vice versa)

Comment: @Stultuske: Yes I know, hence my first line in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can fallthrough - [Can I use OR statements in Java switches?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9566263/can-i-use-or-statements-in-java-switches)

```
case A:
case B:
    System.out.println("hi from" + myEnum.getName());
```

Comment: then how would you deal with the lines that are only supposed to run in case A ?